# Pandas df: Replace the value in a column for the 1st instance in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda df that may have duplicate id. For each id group, for the 1st occurrence, I want wt to be filled with wt_x.
The below shows the initial df and the desired df. Thank you

**Initial DF**

```
id wt wt_x
1  12  33  
1  23  33
2  45  99
2  45  99
2  45  99
3  12  100
```

**Desired DF**

```
id wt wt_x
1  33  33  
1  23  33
2  99  99
2  45  99
2  45  99
3  100  100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
    'wt': [12, 23, 45, 45, 45, 12],
    'wt_x': [33, 33, 99, 99, 99, 100]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
first_occurrence_mask = ~df.duplicated(subset='id')
df.loc[first_occurrence_mask, 'wt'] = df.loc[first_occurrence_mask, 'wt_x']
print(df)
```

Output

```
   id   wt  wt_x
0   1   33    33
1   1   23    33
2   2   99    99
3   2   45    99
4   2   45    99
5   3  100   100
```